# Copy rows based on duplicate values in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table and I would like to copy the rows if the order ID and contract is the same

[image: a busy cat]

I would like to get the macro to do this:

[image: a busy cat]

Could you guys give me a push to the right direction to accomplish this? thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any instance here where they are. Are you saying that the last two digits of `24` in `124` match the last two digits of `24` in `6CV4 P0924`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say if there are similar order IDs and similar contracts then copy the rows. So, in the example above we have 5 rows where order ID = 111 AND contract=6CU4 P0920.                  There could be a case where you have the same order IDs but different contracts (i.e. say with the example above a new row with Order Id = 111, Contract = 6CU4 P1922 is created). In this case this new row will be separate from the other 5 rows

Comment: What constitutes similar? Have you tried anything yet? Any code started?

Comment: If they are sorted by `ID` and then by `Contract`, then you could loop through the data and mark the end of a range with something like `if cells(i,1)<>cells(i+1,1) and cells(i,3)<>cells(i+1,3) ... ` Then row `i` would be the last row in a range of "similar" items.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this code more effient, but this is the "push to the right direction to accomplish this" :)

```
Sub myMacro()

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' decleration

    Dim rowData As Integer, rowNew As Integer
        rowData = 1
        rowNew = 1
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' put first two entries

    Range("H" & rowNew, "J" & rowNew).Value = Range("A" & rowData, "C" & rowData).Value
    rowNew = rowNew + 1
    rowData = rowData + 1

    Range("H" & rowNew, "J" & rowNew).Value = Range("A" & rowData, "C" & rowData).Value
    rowNew = rowNew + 1
    rowData = rowData + 1
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' loop through all of column A entries

    Do While Range("A" & rowData).Value <> ""

        ' similar entry found
        If Range("A" & rowData).Value = Range("A" & rowData - 1).Value Then

            Range("H" & rowNew, "J" & rowNew).Value = Range("A" & rowData, "C" & rowData).Value
            rowNew = rowNew + 1
            rowData = rowData + 1

        ' similar entry Not found
        Else

            rowNew = rowNew + 1
            Range("H" & rowNew, "J" & rowNew).Value = Range("A1:C1").Value
            rowNew = rowNew + 1

            Range("H" & rowNew, "J" & rowNew).Value = Range("A" & rowData, "C" & rowData).Value
            rowNew = rowNew + 1
            rowData = rowData + 1

        End If

    Loop
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

End Sub
```